# MySQL return all records in a hierarchical struture

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I've got a simple hierarchical table 'Groups' where I store the parent-id of each child.

I'm trying to query each member of the table Groups with the following query:

```
SELECT groups.name  AS 'Group Name', 
       groups1.name AS 'Group1 Name' 
FROM   groups 
       LEFT JOIN groups groups1 
              ON groups.id = groups1.parent_id 
WHERE  groups.parent_id = 0 
ORDER  BY groups.id, 
          groups1.id
```

and I'm getting:

|Group Name......................................|Group1 Name............|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Assets...............................................|Fixed Assets..............|
|Assets...............................................|Current Assets..........|
|Assets...............................................|Investments...............|
|Liabilities and Owners Equity............|Capital Account.........|
|Liabilities and Owners Equity............|Current Liabilities......|
|Incomes............................................|Direct Incomes...........|

But what I really want is a line for each node even if there is a child i.e.:

|Group Name......................................|Group1 Name............|
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Assets...............................................|..................................|
|Assets...............................................|Fixed Assets..............|
|Assets...............................................|Current Assets..........|
|Assets...............................................|Investments...............|
|Liabilities and Owners Equity............|....................................|
|Liabilities and Owners Equity............|Capital Account.........|
|Liabilities and Owners Equity............|Current Liabilities......|
|Incomes............................................|..................................|
|Incomes............................................|Direct Incomes...........|

Is there any way to do this with a query or queries?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting parent_id to 0 for a top-level entry, set parent_id to itself (that is, parent_id = id).  Then join the top-level to all "children" which will include itself.

```
SELECT parent.name AS `Group Name`, 
  IF(parent.id = child.id, '', child.name) AS `Group1 Name` 
FROM groups AS parent JOIN groups AS child 
  ON ((parent.id = child.parent_id))) 
WHERE parent.parent_id = parent.id 
ORDER BY parent.id, child.id
```

Note you don't need the LEFT OUTER JOIN, because there's guaranteed to be at least one "child".

You could also use the Closure Table design I have described in several posts on Stack Overflow:

- [What is the most efficient/elegant way to parse a flat table into a tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192220/what-is-the-most-efficient-elegant-way-to-parse-a-flat-table-into-a-tree/192462#192462)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that gives you a few extra fields, but it needs to do that in order to order the results properly. You can technically wrap another select around the output of this select, if you would like to clean up the output a little bit.

```
(
    SELECT groups.id AS parent_id, groups1.id AS child_id, groups.name  AS 'Group Name', 
       IF(LENGTH(groups1.name), groups1.name, '') AS 'Group1 Name' 
    FROM   groups 
    LEFT JOIN groups groups1 ON groups.id = groups1.parent_id 
    WHERE  groups.parent_id = 0
) 
UNION 
(
    SELECT groups.id AS parent_id, NULL AS child_id, groups.name  AS 'Group Name', '' AS 'Group1 Name' FROM groups WHERE groups.parent_id = 0
) 
ORDER BY parent_id, child_id
```

Comment: Superb - that works great and I'd been struggling with that for days

Comment: Wonderful :) Please be sure to accept this as the answer if it truly solved your problem, it will help your approval rate